# In Part of phones ，Sytem seting app can find ble device,But use other app cannot find device

Tags: python, bluetooth-lowenergy, bluez

OS: Ubuntu 18.0
Language: Python 3.6
Framework: python-bluezero
https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero

I run demo code ble_uart.py with bluetooth le
https://github.com/ukBaz/python-bluezero/blob/master/examples/ble_uart.py

Then use many phones (include android and iOS) to scan , but part of android phones cannot find the devices, all of ios phones cannot find device

but with system setiing - bluetooth can find this device

Is it related to the ble service uuid definition

Comment: How are you scanning for the devices with your phone?

Comment: Lightblue  or nRF connect or use code

Comment: I has resolved the problem,  It relates to the service uuid defination. use FFE0 ,the device can be scanned by lightblue

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked if you have provided location permission and enabled location services. This has been a requirement from Android lollipop onwards atleast.

Answer (score 0):

I has resolved the problem, It relates to the service uuid defination. use FFE0 ,the device can be scanned by lightblue